# NGINX act as a forward proxy?

Tags: nginx, web, server, proxy

is NGINX best solution to used as a forward proxy server?

[current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD1IF.png)

What do you think will be the advantage and disadvantage of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use nginx as a forward proxy https://nginxproxymanager.com/

Personally I would utilize some kind of load balancer in front to make sure traffic is properly maintained across the three servers. Luckily you can do this as well with nginx

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

But there are other technologies out there that you could use as well. But it all depends on budget and how much self maintaining do you want to do

ambassador is another load balancer tech
https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/running/load-balancer/

If you want to deal with other services then there is also aws load balancer services and such.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! those URLs helps a lot.